# python + Maya: Calculating addition

Tags: python, maya

When I evaluate the positions of two nodes, I'm trying to find the difference of the x values. As a result i get this equation which doesn't return the expected value which would be something closer to zero in this specific case.

How should I process this stuff, should I round the numbers? Of is there a function or operation I'm not doing that I should? I've been getting some odd results in maya when trying to place a node using this equation as the placement of the x. I wasn't sure if it not return a value .000000095 instead of 9.5^10 was causing the problem.

```
nodes = cmds.ls(long = True, selection = True, type = 'dagNode')
val = -2.57873129845 + 2.57873225212

cmds.xform(nodes[0], t=[val,0,0], ws=True )
```

Comment: I get 9.536699998591303e-07 which is really close to zero. What do you expect in this particular case?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it not return a value .000000095 instead of 9.5^10 was causing the problem.

Comment: @JokerMartini, open a Python shell and type `.000000095`. You'll see it outputs `9.5000000000000004e-08`. There is no issue here. It's just different representations of the same number.

Comment: Yeah it was a bug on my end in the math that was producing a weird result in maya. Thank you for clearing it up.